# Simplest classifier with Weka

Tags: java, classification, weka, bayesian, text-classification

I'm traing to classify text using the Weka naive Bayesian. 
I trained the classifier over this two phrases:
en "Hello"
it "La casa è"

The idea is to create a classifier for each n-grams size (1<= n <= 5) and then compute the result as a weighed sum of the probabilities of each classifier for each language.

The code for training the classifier with a specific n-grams size is the following:

```
public void evaluate(int sizeGrams) throws Exception {
    trainData.setClassIndex(0);
    filter = new StringToWordVector();
    filter.setAttributeIndices("last");
    MyNGramTokenizer ngram_tok = new MyNGramTokenizer();
    ngram_tok.setNGramMinSize(sizeGrams);
    ngram_tok.setNGramMaxSize(sizeGrams);
    filter.setTokenizer(ngram_tok);
    classifier = new FilteredClassifier();
    classifier.setFilter(filter);
    classifier.setClassifier(new NaiveBayes());
    Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(trainData);
    eval.crossValidateModel(classifier, trainData, 2, new Random(1));
}
```

If I try to classify the text "casa" the results are:

```
Classifying
casa
Classify ngrams:
Size 1
{it=0.9999999999966434,  en=3.356604905116531E-12}
Size 2
{it=0.9999999975201513,  en=2.479848603138736E-9}
Size 3
{it=0.49999999999999617,  en=0.5000000000000039}
Size 4
{it=1.8321005992748378E-6,  en=0.9999981678994008}
Size 5
{it=2.479848603138678E-9,  en=0.9999999975201515}
```

Who knows why the probabilities of the italian class shrink with respect to the n-grams size, while that of english class grow up?

I aspected the quite the opposite.

Thanks

Comment: What is your tokenizer? Are you using words as grams?

Comment: No, i use characters as grams, for example "house" with n-grams of size 2 is "ho", "ou", "us" and "se".